# Как объединить 2 файла cvs с заменой одинаковых строк и добавлением недостающих?

Tags: csv

Есть два файла csv которые необходимо каждые сутки объединять в один общий при этом добавлять не достающие и удалять одинаковые строчки, есть онлайн [сервис](http://www.filesmerge.com/ru/merge-csv-files) который полностью удовлетворяет решение задачи, но хотелось бы делать это локально на своем пк дабы в последующем автоматизировать задачу.

Comment: @nick_n_a то есть если в таблице№1 будет строчка и в таблице№2 будет такая же строчка, то в итоге должна остаться строчка из таблицы№2

Comment: *если в таблице№1 будет строчка и в таблице№2 будет такая же строчка, то в итоге должна остаться строчка из таблицы№2* Если они полностью идентичны - не пофиг, какая из двух? а если нет - то фраза непонятна. *хотелось бы делать это локально на своем пк* Какими средствами? Написание программы, выполняющей требуемое, на практически любом языке - весьма несложная задача... я бы её реализовал, например, на VBS, используя, наверное, Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: Думаю *Слияние* подходит больше чем замена. Ещё можно сказать с удалением дублей. А замена - что на что меняем?

Comment: Да именно слияние, если на VBS то как можно пример привести, требуется так: если строчки равны по первому столбцу то вся строчка вставляется из таблицы №2

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Вы ожидаете что в ответе? Ссылки на готовые программы? Windows/Linux/Другое? Код на SQL, VBS, PHP, с++? Алгоритм как склеить в excel? Что-то другое?